# Docker Bind Mount: error while creating mount source path, permission denied

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to run the NVIDIA PyTorch container [`nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.01-py3`](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel_22-01.html#rel_22-01) on a Linux system, and I need to mount a directory of the host system (that I have R/W access to) in the container. I know that I need to use bind mounts, and here's what I'm trying:

I'm in a directory `/home/<user>/test`, which has the directory `dir-to-mount`. (The <user> account is mine).

```sh
docker run -it -v $(pwd)/dir-to-mount:/workspace/target nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.01-py3
```

Here's the error output:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/home/<user>/test/dir-to-mount': mkdir /home/<user>/test: permission denied.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

As far as I know, docker will only need to create the directory to be mounted if it doesn't exist already. [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/):

> The file or directory does not need to exist on the Docker host already. It is created on demand if it does not yet exist.

I suspected that maybe the docker process does not have access; I tried `chmod 777` with `dir-to-mount` as well as with `test`, but that made no difference.

So what's going wrong?

**[Edit 1]**
I am able to mount my user's entire home directory with the same command, but cannot mount other directories inside the home directory.

**[Edit 2]**
Here are the permissions:

- home directory: `drwx------`
- `test`: `drwxrwxrwx`
- `dir-to-mount`: `drwxrwxrwx`

Comment: What are the permissions on the path leading to your path? E.g. use "ls -l" on /home/<user>, /home/<user>/test... and show those results as well. Also, is your Dockerfile using a USER statement? Or does the container run as root?

Comment: @DanLowe Added the permissions in the question. Also, the container runs as root.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command with sudo as:

`sudo docker run -it -v $(pwd)/dir-to-mount:/workspace/target nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.01-py3`

Comment: My account is part of the `docker` group, so it does have permissions to run containers. It's the bind mount that seems to be the issue. Also, I don't have sudo privileges on this system

Comment: `mkdir /home/<user>/test: permission denied`, strongly indicates that you don't have write privileges i.e. sudo access to that file system. Is there any way you can get sudo access? Maybe try default root password, if it works.

Comment: I have write permissions in `/home/<user>/test`, it's probably the case that `docker` doesn't. Also, my account is not in the sudoers list; this is a university server, so I really cannot do anything with sudo.

Comment: Yes, docker doesn't, and that mkdir command is executed by the daemon. We should be able to work around without sudo too. Are you able to execute solo command `mkdir /home/<user>/test` and its parent or child directories to get some more info?

Comment: Yes I can do that. The /home/<user> directory is my home directory, and I have full R/W access inside it

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can mount my home directory as a home directory (inside of `/home/<username>`), and this just works.

```sh
docker run -it -v $HOME:$HOME nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.01-py3
```

I don't know why the `/home/<username>` path is special, I've tried looking through the docs but I could not find anything relevant.